# Is there a way to issue the * commands to the mobile provider to query things like balance, minutes remaining etc from within android app?

Tags: java, android, mobile, telecommunication

The cellphone network provider in my area has a few functions you can do by dialing what I am calling the "star commands", that is you type and asterix(*) followed by the code of your command and press send and you are able to query account balances and a whole slew of other functions that the cell network has made available. I think this is common place among all cell networks.

I want to be able to make these commands and read the responses, issue other commands based on those responses and so on, all from within my android app.

Does anyone has experience doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Those commands are known as USSD commands. You can use [`TelephonyManager.sendUssdRequest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#sendUssdRequest(java.lang.String,%20android.telephony.TelephonyManager.UssdResponseCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) to send a USSD command, providing a callback to receive the result form the mobile network.

Bear in mind Android only introduced support for invoking them programmatically in API 26 (Android 8.0). If you need that functionality on any earlier Android, you'll need to do something hacky, writing some code that automates pressing buttons of the system UI